# Agrupar últimas filas en una sola sumando valores - MySQL

Tags: mysql

Tengo esta tabla en mi base de datos mysql:

```
date       | client | total
2015-01-01 | john   | 85.00
2015-01-01 | alfred | 35.00
2015-01-01 | georgy | 125.00
2015-01-01 | linda  | 42.00
2015-01-01 | alex   | 76.00
2015-01-01 | john   | 94.00
2015-01-01 | john   | 75.30
```

Quiero agrupar los nombres de los clientes calculando la suma total y el porcentaje correspondiente, así que ejecuto este query:

```
 SELECT client, total, round(total*100/t.th,1) as percent 
 FROM ( 
 SELECT client, sum(total) as total 
 FROM mytable 
 WHERE date='2015-01-01' 
 GROUP BY `client`) c 
 JOIN ( select sum(total) as th from mytable 
 WHERE date='2015-01-01') t 
 order by percent desc
```

El query funciona correctamente mostrándome este resultado:

```
client | total | percent
john   | 254.3 | 47.8
georgy | 125   | 23.5
alex   | 76    | 14.3
linda  | 42    | 7.9
alfred | 35    | 6.6
```

Ahora me gustaría que las últimas filas estén agrupadas en una sola obteniendo un resultado como este ejemplo que agrupa las últimas 3:

```
client | total | percent
john   | 254.3 | 47.8
georgy | 125   | 23.5
others | 135   | 28.8
```

Cómo puedo cambiar mi consulta para obtener este resultado?

Agradeceré su respuesta.

Comment: mas que un ejemplo, se necesita saber las reglas claras para agrupar el resto de los registros. se puede hacer, pero una query no es el mejor metodo para hacer esto (mejor que lo haga la vista)

Answer (score 1):

Lo que puedes hacer es usar UNION, deben tener las mismas columnas, tipo de datos y orden. Además de eso lo que haria seria usar los LIMIT para tomar lo que quieres en la consulta.

```
SELECT client, total, round(total*100/t.th,1) as percent 
 FROM ( 
 SELECT client, sum(total) as total 
 FROM mytable 
 WHERE date='2015-01-01' 
 GROUP BY `client`) c 
 JOIN ( select sum(total) as th from mytable 
 WHERE date='2015-01-01') t 
 order by percent desc LIMIT 0,2
UNION
SELECT "other", total, round(total*100/t.th,1) as percent 
 FROM ( 
 SELECT sum(total) as total 
 FROM mytable 
 WHERE date='2015-01-01' LIMIT 2,3) c 
 JOIN ( select sum(total) as th from mytable 
 WHERE date='2015-01-01') t 
 order by percent desc LIMIT 0,2
```

Saludos

Comment: He probado tu query pero me muestra error `Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY`